# calling javascript function inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I am following the Google Map API tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple), specifically the JAVASCRIPT + HTML version. I believe the relevant part would be

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

I am trying to use bootstrap for the page with two fluid containers, one of which will contain the map. I am following this [fluid layout example](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts) from Bootstrap. So I have something like

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span2">
  {% for q in qs %}
    <p>{{ q.name }} {{ q.address}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="span10" id="map"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

It does not display the map. I am wondering if

```
<div class="span10" id="map"></div>
```

is the right thing to do here, and whether I should change anything else.

Edit:

```
<div id="map"></div> <- This works
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span10" id="map"></div> <- This doesn't work
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And do you actually call the `initMap` function anywhere ?

Comment: @adeneo I realize that I am actually not.. but when I was following the tutorial <div id="map"></div> this just displayed the map. How does this work like this?

Comment: Have you checked the CSS on the bootstrap elements? It may be that you are accidentally getting a 0 height and need to set a specific size. Looking at the elements in your browser tools should show you whether a map is actually there and just not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

with

```
(function () {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}())
```